# less stops my script; why is that and how to avoid?

Tags: bash, shell-script, signals, job-control, subshell

I have this Bash script named as `s` in current directory:

```
#!/bin/bash
pipe_test() {
    ( set -m; (
        $1
    ); set +m ) | 
    (
        $2
    )
}
pipe_test "$1" "$2"
```

If I call e.g.

```
./s yes less
```

the script gets stopped. (Similar thing happens if I use any other pager I tried instead of `less`, i.e. `more` and `most`.) I can continue it by `fg` builtin, though.

I want to have job control (enabled by `set -m`) for the subshell to have a distinct process group ID for the processes of the subshell.

Information about my system:

```
$ bashbug
...
Machine: x86_64
OS: linux-gnu
Compiler: gcc
Compilation CFLAGS: -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/bash-cP61jF/bash-5.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format->
uname output: Linux jarnos-OptiPlex-745 5.4.0-29-generic #33-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 29 14:32:27 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU>
Machine Type: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

Bash Version: 5.0
Patch Level: 16
Release Status: release
```

```
$ less --version
less version: 551
```

Comment: @roaima oh, you are right, but I added a call.

Comment: It's probably related to `current terminal process group ID` mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Basics.html#Job-Control-Basics). I don't know the mechanics good enough to write a decent answer, but maybe this comment will allow you to advance your research.

Comment: Fortunately this can be worked around using named pipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why that happens is because enabling job control (`set -m`) brings along not just process grouping, but also the machinery for handling "foreground" and "background" jobs. This "machinery" implies that each command run in turn while job control is enabled becomes the foreground process group.

Therefore, in short, when that sub-shell (the left part of your pipeline) enables job control it literally steals the terminal from the entire pipeline, which had it until then and which, in your example, includes the `less` process, thus making it become background and, as such, not allowed to use the terminal any more. It therefore gets stopped because `less` does keep accessing the terminal.

By issuing `fg` you give the terminal back to the entire pipeline, hence to `less`, and all ends well. Unless you run additional commands within the job-controlling sub-shell, because in such case each additional command would steal the terminal again.

One way around it is to simply run your job-controlled sub-sub-shell in background:

```bsh
( set -m; (
        $1
    ) & set +m ) | 
    (
        $2
    )
```

You will have the command expressed by `$1` run in its distinct process group as you wish, while the backgrounded mode prevents stealing the terminal, thus leaving it to the pipeline and hence to `$2`.

Naturally this requires that the command in `$1` does not want to read the terminal itself, otherwise it will be the one to get stopped as soon as it attempts to do it.

Also, likewise to as I said above, any additional job-controlled sub-sub-shell you might like to add would require the same "backgrounding" treatment, all along until you `set +m`, otherwise each additional job-controlled sub-sub-shell would steal the terminal again.

That said, if all you need process grouping for is to kill processes, you might consider using `pkill` to target them. For instance `pkill -P` will send a signal to the processes whose *parent* is the indicated PID. This way you can target all children (but not grand-children) of your sub-process by just knowing the sub-process's PID.

Comment: The code seems to work fine, even better than you tell. Job control seems to be disabled within the sub-sub shell and I can add additional commands besides `$1` there without `less` being stopped. Can you give an example of a command `$1` that would read terminal and stop `less`?

Comment: As for killing grand-children, there is [rkill](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/241170/111181) but you may have to install the package providing it separately.

Comment: Yes, you can run additional commands within the backgrounded job-controlled sub-sub-shell, ie besides `$1` or with a `$1` expressing several commands which would all stay within the innermost parentheses. Those will all belong to the same process group, job control is implicitly disabled there. But should you run additional job-controlled sub-sub-shells without the `&`, those will steal the terminal again. Try `(set -m; (seq 1 100; ls) & (echo bye bye; sleep 100); set +m) | less`: the sub-sub-shell running `seq` and `ls` will not disturb `less`, but the one running `echo` and `sleep` will

Comment: It may be enough to run commands in job-controlled **sub-shell** to make it stop: `(set -m; (seq 1 100; ls) & echo bye bye; sleep 0; set +m) | less`.

Comment: Of course. I showed additional sub-sub-shells just to make the whole thing homogeneous. A side-note for clarity: the *sub*-shell is job-controll_ing_, not job-controll_ed_, because it's the one having the `set -m`. The *sub-sub*-shell is job-controlled. Unless you use `set -m` in there too, in which case it also becomes job-controll_ing_ and complicates things even more. Also, the `set +m` at the very end is useless. It would be useful to disable the stealing if there were additional commands after it. A small enough `sleep` does stop `less`, but it is relinquished as soon as `sleep` ends.

Comment: So now that the job_controlled _sub-sub-shell_ is running in background, job control can not put any job in the foreground making pipeline flow as usual. I wish I would found some documentation about this.

Comment: You _can_ put any job back to foreground at will. You can `fg` at some point in the job-controlling sub-shell to assign the terminal to any one of its background jobs, but of course will steal it from `less`. In the job-controlling sub-shell you can also `wait` for its job-controlled sub-sub-shells, so as to keep synchronous operation for the job-controlling sub-shell itself while not stealing the terminal. In general, for not too complicated set-ups you may be able to handle things up to some extent, but you need to synchronize everything carefully between the parts of the main pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `set -m` solves the problem (what is that to do anyway?).

Three processes are stopped by the kernel via `SIGTTOU`:

- the script process
- a subshell
- `less`

But not `yes`. Its process is put into a separate process group; probably by the `set -m`. So the kernel tries to hit all processes in that pipeline but misses one. This missing is not the reason for the "stopped" message, though.

Usually `SIGTTOU` is caused by a background process trying to write to the terminal. But that is not the only possible reason:

> int SIGTTOU
>   This is similar to SIGTTIN, but is generated when a process in a background job attempts to write to the terminal or set its modes. Again, the default action is to stop the process. SIGTTOU is only generated for an attempt to write to the terminal if the TOSTOP output mode is set; see Output Modes.

See https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Signals.html

The last syscall before the  is (by `less`):

```
ioctl(3, SNDCTL_TMR_STOP or TCSETSW, {B38400 opost isig -icanon -echo ...}) = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
```

So my assessment is that for some strange reason (i.e. `set -m`) the pipeline is put in the background. There are several syscalls like

```
ioctl(255, TIOCSPGRP, [23715]
```

by different processes. The last one is by the subshell

```
ioctl(2, TIOCSPGRP, [23718]) = 0
```

making `yes` the foreground process group after making it the leader of its own process group (with no other members) by

```
setpgid(23718, 23718 <unfinished ...>
```

Comment: If you replace `less` by `cat` it will not stop.

Comment: "I want to have job control for the subshell to have a distinct process group ID for the processes of the subshell."

Comment: @jarno Because `cat` does not try to reconfigure the terminal. "to have a distinct process group ID for the processes of the subshell" just shifts the question: What for? The only "solution" I see is to delay the execution of `set -m` until `less` is done with the terminal initialization. But how to do that cleanly... Not even `less --no-init` works.

Comment: To be able to send a signal to all processes that are running due to the subshell (and only to them). I can do that if I use named pipe, and there is no such stopping then.

Comment: ^including the subshell itself.

Comment: @jarno It might be a better idea to create a cgroup for the subshell. That would make it easy to signal all processes in the subshell.

Comment: Oh, is that something you can do in Bash shell?

Comment: @jarno I haven't used that in too long so I cannot give you a detailed description now but basically you create a new cgroup and put the subshell ID in it as soon as it is known. When sending signals you just read the cgroup member list and run `kill` individually. I am not aware of a "send signal to all members of cgroup x" command.